# convert the dbf file to csv using dbf2mysql?

Tags: mysql, unix, ubuntu, command, dbf

I'm using this command to convert the DBF to CSV but command run successfully but not create any table in the database.

```
dbf2mysql  -U **** -P *****  -t test -cc <filename>.DBF
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the filename the correct case? is it not filename.DBF or FILENAME.DBF

Use with the -vv switch to see the verbose output

You may need to add these switches

-h localhost

-d yourdatabasename

Answer (score 0):

You must create at least the database and possibly the empty table.

Then use a command like the one below which creates the table and inserts data (your -cc parameter only creates the table and doesn't import data).

```
dbf2mysql -U root -P *** -t test_table -h localhost -d testdatabase -c AUSLIEFERUNG.DBF
```

Answer (score 0):

This command flag sequence works.

```
dbf2mysql -h localhost -q -d mysql_database -t your_table -c -U mysql_user -P mysql_password /path/dbf_file
```

Parameter -c truncate the table each time, and write then your dbf
file to table

Parameter -q is quick mod

And `man` `dbf2mysql` for all options.